# touchscreen gestures just move mouse

Tags: lubuntu, touchscreen

I am running Lubuntu 14.10, and my touchscreen does not function properly, it does not seem to recognize any gestures.

Where I expect it to scroll on a swipe, it just moves the mouse pointer. It always moves the mouse pointer and does nothing else.

I vaguely remember that in the beginning gestures used to work and I perhaps installed something that disabled this.

I have `synclient TouchpadOff=1` in my `.profile`, I thought that this is the cause, but it does not seem so.

Answer (score -1):

You can find your settings by entering `synclient -l`in your terminal.
If you want to enable the two finger scroll down.  Make sure that HorizTwoFingerScroll=1
Look here for more information.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/Mouse#Touchpad_settings